# Log in loop ASP.NET MVC view with Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I just uploaded an MVC application to my live server. Before doing so, I created a user ('anders') after creating the necessary tables and stored procedures for authentication via the `aspnet_regsql` command in the VS2008 Command Prompt. I successfully tested, locally, that I need to log in before (or while) accessing this view:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I made a back up of my local database, and restored this to my live server. Before testing the view, I verified that I can log in with my newly-created user. However, when I try to access the view after logging in, I get redirected indefinitely to the log in page.

### New Info

Looks like something else is going on, but the above information may still be useful. Apparently my user is **not** in the admin group, even though I looked into the database and verified that my `UserID` is in the `dbo.aspnet_Roles` table and the `RoleID` corresponds with the admin role. I found this out by changing the code at the top of the master page where it welcomes the logged in user, and noticed that it returned false:

```
Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name) %></b>!
(<%= Html.Encode(Page.User.IsInRole("admin")) %>)
```

Both my user and the newly created 'stackoverflow' (password is passw0rd, for you guys to check it out) user are supposed to be in the admin role, but for some reason they are not.

Any help with tracking down the reason why my users aren't being recognized as being in the 'admin' role would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[Link to my live server](http://anders-leet.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any caching technique ? this maybe the reason.

also you need to verify that the RoleProvider is working, but without more details I cant help more

Comment: Alright. What more information can I post to help you out? Also, how can I verify that the RoleProvider is working? I have not implemented a custom one.

Comment: Figured it out, the default RoleProvider was mapped to a local database. Tweaked some settings in the web.config got things working properly. Thanks for the hint, it probably saved me a good deal of time!

Comment: Here u're some points to check.
1- Make sure your Web.Config is using correct settings
2- You can put a diagnostics page that display providers working
3- You can run your locally hosted code, with connection string to the remote database server.
4- Default RoleProvider needs a database, Make sure that you have accecss to it, it maybe a hosting limitation.

Comment: Seems we were writing at the same time :D, anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same Issue. In web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
...
```

Was set to false at server's config but not local's.